# How to print colored string in Arm assembly

Tags: string, assembly, colors, arm

how do i print a colored string using arm assembly language?
for example i want to print following text in red color located in `.data` part. how to do it?

```
.data
text1 : .asciz "Hello" `
```

Comment: That depends on your operating system and your terminal and how much effort you want to make. You could try ANSI color codes and hope it works. PS: How would you do it in C? :)

Comment: step 1) throw away your ARM device 2) buy ZX Spectrum Next 3) ask again here, I will show you how to change separate pixels and colors on the screen by modifying values in video ram in Z80 assembly (although you may not want to follow this advice, because then you will have to draw the characters per pixel, and not just by providing ASCII string... then again, you can use your own custom font! Winning!)

Comment: @Jester hi ,as i know in c we can do it by escape sequence+ansi codes using sprintf  command. i will try to compile c then to assembly,thanks :)

Comment: If you know that ansi codes work in your environment, then the question is really "how to print a string" (whether it contains color codes or not). So, do you know how to print strings at least? Or maybe you don't know how to embed color codes into the string? That depends on your assembler, you might have to split your `text1` into parts and use `.ascii` and `.byte` (or equivalent)

Comment: @Jester yes i know how to print string , i tried to print hello in red using printf("\x1b[31mHELLO\x1b[0m"); in c and compiled it to assembly, it is more complex than i think.thanks :)

Comment: @jester got it :) thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the ANSI escape characters for colors.

```
.data
text: .ascii "\033[31mHELLO\033[0m\000"
```